# Order (Slowest to Fastest) Big O running times

Tags: data-structures, big-o, time-complexity

Assuming that N is very large, can anybody help me in ordering the following list for Big O running times from Slowest to Fastest.

O(N^2)
O(N)
O(1)
O(N!)
O(2^N)
O(N log N)
O(N^3)
O(log N)

Comment: No, that isn't "help". That would be *giving you the answer*. What do you think the answer is?

Comment: *help:* Substitute numbers `10, 100, 1000, 10000...` for N in each and see how they increase. This may not be necessary for most equations though, If you understand `Big O`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide O(A/B) to see if O(A) is asymptotically larger than O(B). (Take the limit as n->infinity. For example N^2/N = N, which blows up to infinity, so N^2>N asymptotically. Alternately, N/N^2 = 1/N which approaches 0, so N

Then you can graph them to check your work and get intuition (though graphs like this can easily "lie" if you graph them too close to the origin, and/or there are smaller hidden terms).

Comment: Edited since MitchWheat's comment.

Comment: You mean to say that the larger one is the slower one? Like in your above derived one, N^2 > N so N^2 is slower?

Comment: @nommyravian: O(...) notation doesn't have a concept of "slower" or "faster". If O(...) represents computing time, larger will be slower.  In the contrived case that O(...) represents computers-per-second, smaller will be slower. If O(...) represents memory, larger will be worse (neither faster/slower). If O(...) represents armadillos, the units will be armadillos.